# How to build FaceDetect/cnn_face_detection project on github?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, github, build

I want to use the https://github.com/FaceDetect/cnn_face_detection project stored on Github repository but it shows so many different files and no proper documentation is available. Can anyone tell me how to build that github project into an executable?

Comment: Try to find `release` link on the project page. Binary executable files are usually published as a release. If there is no such link, you probably need to learn how to compile from source.

Comment: 1. Doing this for _any_ project is way too incredibly broad, 2. this isn't a programming question, and 3. you should ask the project's maintainers how to use it, not us, especially if 4. you won't even mention which project it is.

Comment: Project is https://github.com/FaceDetect/cnn_face_detection. It shows many release folders

Comment: The https://github.com/FaceDetect/cnn_face_detection project seems to be written in C/C++ and I suspect designed for Windows, given the presence of VC6 and VC2010 folders under the Make folder.  If you really want help building this project I'd suggest removing the python tag from this question and adding visual-studio and visual-studio-c++ tags.  On the other hand, if you want to do CNN face detection with python a google search should reveal some python-based implementations e.g. https://github.com/leezivin/FaceDetection_CNN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GitHub is mostly used for code.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) in [various languages](https://github.com/blog/2047-language-trends-on-github)

How to make any github project usable or executable is specific to the language and to the kind of the project itself.

Also it [need to be careful with the license terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521080/can-i-use-the-code-in-a-github-project-which-does-not-have-a-license-specified), the state of reliability and completeness of the project you intend to work on (i.e: github.com/leezivin/FaceDetection_CNN – snakecharmerb); The fact that the specific project you mention, at the time, do not have a README.md and a license file jet , let's suggest to contact [the author or someone contribute/commit the sources](https://github.com/AlfredXiangWu) for any further informations.

btw the project you mention appears to be a **c++ language** project; so you need to be able to compile and link it ( Clean an Rebuid ) in some form of executable; [The specific repo: cnn_face_detection](https://github.com/FaceDetect/cnn_face_detection) contains Visual Studio solutions and projects therefore the easy way could be by using Visual Studio and open/import the artifacts ( it depends by version of visual studio you eventually can use ).

It is also required:

1. to choose if you intend to trust ( or not to trust ) the code:

[image: trusting code]

2. to take care to the paths of the dependencies referenced by the prj because *likely* they need to be changed to the actual paths were you clone ( download ) the sources on your own filesystem. if don't do that you may not be able to compile the solution (i.e the three projects contained in the repo ):[image: project settings]

Answer (score 3):

If the github project has `releases` or `tag`, like [tornado releases on github](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/releases).

Then you can run

`pip install https://github.com/project_name/archive/version.tar.gz`

like this:

`pip install https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/archive/v4.3.0.tar.gz` to install the github online project.

But when the project does't have `release` tab. You need clone the project and compile from source.

In most cases, you can run `python setup.py install`.

*The question has a python tag. So take python project as an example.*

Comment: As u see Project i mentioned does not have any release folder except a subfolder has release folder inside it and it only contains some files not any Zip or tar.gz like https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/releases and it also does not contain setup.py file so that i can compile with python

Comment: if Project only have release folder and not any .tar or .zip folder like https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/releases then how can I install it.

Comment: If it is a python project, you can find setup.py and run `python setup.py install`. Otherwise, you can writing a setup.py file by yourself or import the project directly.

Answer (score 2):

1. By looking around the project, you will find folders named "VC2010" and "VC2006".  This is a good clue that this is a Microsoft Visual C (or Visual Studio) based project.  Inside you will find .sln and .vcxproj files, which are "solution" and "project" files, according to [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hx0cxhaw.aspx)
2. Download and install Visual Studio from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx).  There are several options, try the Community edition first.
3. Download the source code of the project from github.  To keep it simple you can just use "Download ZIP" button on the project home page.
4. Run Visual Studio and follow [these directions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179431(v=sql.80).aspx) to open one of the solution (.sln) files:

   - On the File menu, click Open Solution. The Open Solution dialog box opens.
   - Navigate to the solution you want.
   - Click the solution folder, which displays and selects the solution file within the folder. If no solution file is visible, verify that the value in the Files of type list box is Solution Files.
   - Click Open.
5. Build using [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tdasz7h.aspx).  At this point you either have an .exe or a .dll (depending on which project you're building).